# How do you determine the sample size of a normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation

I am presented with the question:

> The photoresist thickness in semiconductor manufacturing has a mean of
>   10 micrometers and a standard deviation of 1 micrometer. Assume that
>   the thickness is normally distributed and that the thicknesses of
>   different wafers are independent.
>
> (a) Determine the probability that the average thickness of 10 wafers
>   is either greater than 11 or less than 9 micrometers.
>
> (b) Determine the number of wafers that needs to be measured such that
>   the probability that the average thickness exceeds 11 micrometers is
>   0.01.
>
> (c) If the mean thickness is 10 micrometers, what should the standard
>   deviation of thickness equal so that the probability that the average
>   of 10 wafers is either greater than 11 or less than 9 micrometers is
>   0.001?

I thought a) was 1-normalcdf(9,11,10,1), but that answer appears to be wrong... I'm completely stumped on the others - I don't evene know where to start. Any chance someone could explain how to go about answering this question? As always, I'm trying to understand it - not just look for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have certain observations $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ which follow $N(10,1)$ distribution, where $X_i$ denote the thickness of the $i^{th}$ wafer. Then the the average thickness of the $n$ wafers $\bar{X}_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i/n$ follows $N(10,1/n)$ distribution. Then the probability that 
$$P(\bar{X}_n<11~or~\bar{X}_n>9)=P(-1<\bar{X}_n-10<1)=\Phi(\sqrt{n})-\Phi(-\sqrt{n})=2\Phi(\sqrt{n})-1$$
where $\Phi$ is the standard normal CDF. Put $n=10$ to get the value of $(a)$. 
$$P(\bar{X}_n>11)=P\left(\frac{\bar{X}_n-10}{1/\sqrt{n}}>\sqrt{n}\right)=1-\Phi(\sqrt{n})$$
So for $(b)$ find $n$ such that $1-\Phi(n)=0.01$ or $\sqrt{n}=\Phi^{-1}(0.99)$.

For $(c)$ suppose the required standard deviation is $s$. Then solve $s$ for the equation
$$P(\bar{X}_n<11~or~\bar{X}_n>9)=P\left(-\frac{\sqrt{n}}{s}<\frac{\bar{X}_n-10}{s/\sqrt{n}}<\frac{\sqrt{n}}{s}\right)=2\Phi(\sqrt{n}/s)-1=0.001$$
when $n=10$. Or
$$s=\frac{\sqrt{10}}{\Phi^{-1}(1.001/2)}$$

Comment: correctly said. Made the rquired edits.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $t_k$ are the wafer thicknesses, each has distribution ${\cal N} (\mu, \sigma^2)$, and the $t_k$ are independent.

Then $t_1+\cdots +t_n$ will then have distribution ${\cal N} (n\mu, n\sigma^2)$, and so the quantity $\frac{t_1+\cdots + t_n-n \mu}{\sqrt{n} \sigma}$ will have distribution ${\cal N}(0,1)$, and has CDF $\Phi$. That is, $P(\frac{t_1+\cdots t_n-n \mu}{\sqrt{n}} \le x ) = \Phi(x)$. We note that $\Phi(x) = 1-\Phi(-x)$.

(a) We wish to compute the probability that $t_1+\cdots +t_n \notin [n(\mu-\sigma), n(\mu+\sigma)]$, which is the same as the probability that $\frac{t_1+\cdots + t_n-n \mu}{\sqrt{n} \sigma} \notin [-\sqrt{n}, \sqrt{n}]$. Hence the probability is $\Phi(-\sqrt{10}) + (1-\Phi(\sqrt{10})) = 2 \Phi(-\sqrt{10}) \approx 0.0015$.

(b) First we compute the probability that $t_1+\cdots + t_n \ge n(\mu+\sigma) $, and this is the same as the probability that $\frac{t_1+\cdots + t_n-n \mu}{\sqrt{n} \sigma} \ge \sqrt{n}$, which is $1-\Phi(\sqrt{n})$. Then we compute the minimum $n$ such that $1-\Phi(\sqrt{n}) \le 0.01$, and this gives $n=6$.

(c) First we compute the probability that $t_1+\cdots + t_n \notin [9n,11n]$ which is the same as the probability that $\frac{t_1+\cdots + t_n-n \mu}{\sqrt{n} \sigma} \notin [-\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma}, \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma}]$, which is $2 \Phi( -\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma})$. Then we attempt to solve $2 \Phi( -\frac{\sqrt{10}}{\sigma}) = 0.001$, which gives $\sigma \approx 0.96102$.

Comment: Notational nitpick: since $\bar t$ is often used for the empirical means $\frac1n(t_1+\cdots+t_n)$, you might want to replace it by $\mu$, somewhat more canonical for a theoretical mean. (Oh, and +1 for this answer.)

Comment: @Did: Thanks, took your suggestion.

Comment: Good answer... but way over my head. We don't use anything nearly that complicated in class.

Comment: Bummer. I was hoping it would elucidate the thinking behind the problem.